# Drag and Drop files to diferent WxFilePicker controls

Tags: python, user-interface, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I'm creating a GUI where I need to drag and drop different files into different wxFilePicker controls.
Based on this example [wxPython: Dragging a file into window to get file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391490/wxpython-dragging-a-file-into-window-to-get-file-path) I was able to get the filepath from one file into one filepicker or that same filepath for all filepickers with:

```
def updateText(self, text):
        """
        Write text to the wx control
        """
        self.m_filePicker1.SetPath(text)
        self.m_filePicker2.SetPath(text)
        self.m_filePicker3.SetPath(text)
```

Although it worked as it would be expected that solution its not useful.

Do I need to create different panels for each wxfilepicker control or there is another way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Ivo

Here's the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division

import wx
import wx.xrc

########################################################################
class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, window):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        """
        When files are dropped, write where they were dropped and then
        the file paths themselves
        """
        #self.window.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        self.window.updateText("\n%d file(s) dropped at %d,%d:\n" %
                              (len(filenames), x, y))
        print filenames
        for filepath in filenames:
            self.window.updateText(filepath + '\n')



class Test_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(500, 164),
                          style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        bSizer122 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sbSizer2 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Model"), wx.VERTICAL)

        bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        bSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        bSizer10 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        bSizer12 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_staticText1 = wx.StaticText(sbSizer2.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, u"Model File", wx.DefaultPosition,
                                           wx.Size(100, -1), wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.m_staticText1.Wrap(-1)
        bSizer12.Add(self.m_staticText1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer10.Add(bSizer12, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)

        bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_filePicker1 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(sbSizer2.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, u"Select a file",
                                               u"*.*", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        bSizer13.Add(self.m_filePicker1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer10.Add(bSizer13, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer4.Add(bSizer10, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        bSizer14 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_staticText2 = wx.StaticText(sbSizer2.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, u"Data File", wx.DefaultPosition,
                                           wx.Size(100, -1), wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.m_staticText2.Wrap(-1)
        bSizer14.Add(self.m_staticText2, 1, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer11.Add(bSizer14, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)

        bSizer15 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_filePicker2 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(sbSizer2.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, u"Select a file",
                                               u"*.*", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        bSizer15.Add(self.m_filePicker2, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer11.Add(bSizer15, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)

        bSizer4.Add(bSizer11, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer111 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        bSizer141 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_staticText21 = wx.StaticText(sbSizer2.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, u"DoF Labels", wx.DefaultPosition,
                                            wx.Size(100, -1), wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.m_staticText21.Wrap(-1)
        bSizer141.Add(self.m_staticText21, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer111.Add(bSizer141, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)

        bSizer151 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        file_drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)

        self.m_filePicker3 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(sbSizer2.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, u"Select a file",
                                               u"*.*", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        bSizer151.Add(self.m_filePicker3, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer111.Add(bSizer151, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer4.Add(bSizer111, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer3.Add(bSizer4, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        sbSizer2.Add(bSizer3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer122.Add(sbSizer2, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer122)
        self.Layout()

        self.m_filePicker1.SetDropTarget(file_drop_target)

    def updateText(self, text):
        """
        Write text to the wx control
        """
        self.m_filePicker1.SetPath(text)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

class Test_Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=wx.EmptyString, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                          size=wx.Size(500, 300), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.SetSizeHintsSz(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        bSizer239 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_panel8 = Test_Panel(self)#, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        #self.m_panel8 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        bSizer239.Add(self.m_panel8, 1, wx.EXPAND
                      , 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer239)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = Test_Frame(None)
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I think you would be better off using a couple of TreeCtrls or one of the other Tree-like widgets. They support drag and drop a bit easier then using the file picker widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution for the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import wx.xrc

class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, window):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        """
        When files are dropped, write where they were dropped and then
        the file paths themselves
        """
        #self.window.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        self.window.updateText("\n%d file(s) dropped at %d,%d:\n" %
                              (len(filenames), x, y))
        # print filenames
        for filepath in filenames:
            # self.window.updateText(filepath + '\n')
            self.window.updateText(filepath)

class Model_Data(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, label):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(-1, -1),
                          style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        bSizer122 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        bSizer10 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        bSizer12 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_staticText1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, label, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(100, -1),
        #self.m_staticText1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Model File", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(100, -1),
                                           wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.m_staticText1.Wrap(-1)
        bSizer12.Add(self.m_staticText1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer10.Add(bSizer12, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)

        bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_filePicker1 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, u"Select a file", u"*.*",
                                               wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        bSizer13.Add(self.m_filePicker1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer10.Add(bSizer13, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        ##############################################
        file_drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        self.m_filePicker1.SetDropTarget(file_drop_target)
        ##############################################

        bSizer3.Add(bSizer10, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer122.Add(bSizer3, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer122)
        self.Layout()

    def updateText(self, text):
        """
        Write text to the wx control
        """
        self.m_filePicker1.SetPath(text)

    def __del__(self):
        pass


class Generic_Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(-1, -1),
                          style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        bSizer122 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        bSizer10 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        bSizer12 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_staticText1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Model File", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(100, -1),
                                           wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.m_staticText1.Wrap(-1)
        bSizer12.Add(self.m_staticText1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer10.Add(bSizer12, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)

        bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_filePicker1 = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, u"Select a file", u"*.*",
                                               wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.FLP_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        bSizer13.Add(self.m_filePicker1, 1, wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer10.Add(bSizer13, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)

        bSizer3.Add(bSizer10, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        bSizer122.Add(bSizer3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer122)
        self.Layout()
        bSizer122.Fit(self)

    def __del__(self):
        pass


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=wx.EmptyString, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                          size=wx.Size(500, 300), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.SetBackgroundColour('LightGrey')

        self.SetSizeHintsSz(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        bSizer239 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sbSizer8 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Model "), wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_panel1 = Model_Data(sbSizer8.GetStaticBox(),'Model File')

        sbSizer8.Add(self.m_panel1, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.m_panel2 = Model_Data(sbSizer8.GetStaticBox(),'Model Data')
        sbSizer8.Add(self.m_panel2, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.m_panel3 = Model_Data(sbSizer8.GetStaticBox(),'DoF Labels')
            # wx.Panel(sbSizer8.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
            #                      wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        sbSizer8.Add(self.m_panel3, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        bSizer239.Add(sbSizer8, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer239)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = Frame(None)
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```