# add drag and drop support to a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, drag-and-drop

hi I have a **Python** script that does something simple.
it simply convert file.txt to file2.txt
here a very simple script for show you what i want

```
with open("file.txt", encoding="utf-16-le") as file_in:

with open("file2.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as output:
```

I want to add a capability to this script, when i drag **file-text.txt** on this script, script first convert file then output it with name *file-text-**out**.txt*

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using in your Python program? Also: Please, post your code and describe what have you already tried to solve the problem. It is necessary to provide you with any further assistance

Comment: i dont use any gui, i want add drag and drop to script.. its possible>?

Comment: no. this will not be possible.

Comment: i need to create a gui for my script for doing this job? what best program or laibrary to create this drag and drop Ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a Python program with a GUI. Your program must open a graphical window. To write a Python program with a graphical window, you need a GUI framework.

Many GUI framework for Python exist. But not all of them support drag & drop easily.

One possible GUI framework is [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/).

- You need to install wxPython first (There are plenty of [tutorials](https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython) how to do this)
- Then you should try to get this example running: 
  [wxPython: Dragging a file into window to get file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391490/wxpython-dragging-a-file-into-window-to-get-file-path)

I copied the code for class `MyFileDropTarget` that you can find in the link above. I was able to start the program. When started, the program opens this window:

[image]

I was also able to drag and drop a file from my desktop into this window. After I dragged it,  the text "1 file(s) dropped at 86,55: /home/lydia/testfile.txt" appeared in the window. This means that the program understood the event and was able to respond.

When you got this far, I suggest you continue with carefully studying the [getting-started](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started) page from wxPython.